# Micronaut not connecting to db in yml

Tags: postgresql, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have created a new environment for my application and called it docker. I'm trying stuff out so I set it like this:

application-docker.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: time
  server:
    netty:
      access-logger:
        enabled: true
        logger-name: access-logger

datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: POSTGRES
    schema: time
jpa.default.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update

flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
      schemas: time
...
```

However when I try to run my app like this:

```
java -jar target/timeshare-0.1.jar -Dmicronaut.environments=docker -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xmx128m
```

If fails... because it can't connect to localhost!

```
08:11:00.949 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
08:11:02.013 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
```

Why is it trying to connect to localhost? What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Micronaut is not able to locate *application-docker.yml* file and then it is using the default one.

Because you can use for example `-Dmicronaut.environments=not-existing-profile` and even if it does not exist, it does not show any error.

So, make sure you have *application-docker.yml* file in the *src/main/resources* directory and also that the file is really exported into the result jar during build and is located in the root of the jar archive:

```
target/timeshare-0.1-all.jar
├── com
├── META-INF
├── org
├── application-docker.yml
├── application.yml
├── logback.xml
...
```

How are you building the result jar? When you use the **shadowJar** task then it must contain everything.

---

Another option is to use `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` system variable:

```
export MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=docker
```

But this behaves the same way as `-Dmicronaut.environments=docker` startup option.

---

Another option is to specify exact path to the *application-docker.yml* configuration file by the `micronaut.config.files` startup option:

```
java -jar target/timeshare-0.1-all.jar -Dmicronaut.config.files=/some/external/location/application-docker.yml
```

Comment: So obvious now that you laid it out. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I'm glad it helped to you ;-)